# IdentityServer4 only authenticates localhost

Tags: localhost, ssl-certificate, identityserver4

This may be related to my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48837216/identityserver4-and-asp-net-core-only-logging-for-localhost) however because of that it is hard to know.

I am hosting IdentityServer4 and it seems to be working perfectly if all requests are coming from localhost. Anything else it is rejecting however I can log in fine through the web interface.

I am still in development and I am just testing things however I am using

```
AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
```

Is this the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is good till you are in development. Below is the reference from [IdentityServer4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/startup.html)

> Creates temporary key material at startup time. This is for dev only scenarios when you don’t have a certificate to use.